# How to tell the main nodejs script after webpack transpilation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

According to the documetation here https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_accessing_the_main_module:

> When a file is run directly from Node.js, `require.main` is set to its `module`. That means that it is possible to determine whether a file has been run directly by testing `require.main === module`.
>
> For a file `foo.js`, this will be `true` if run via `node foo.js`, but `false` if run by `require('./foo')`.

I am using webpack to transpile my nodejs scripts.

What can I do to have similar behavior for my webpack entry point?

Or, in other words, what condition can I check to have some code in `foo.js` run only if the transpiled script is the result of `webpack --entry foo.js`, but not run if `require('./foo')` was used?